# Abstract submission versus full research paper submission

Tags: publications, ieee, abstract

I am searching for good conferences to submit my hard working. Therefore, I found [a conference](http://www.ectconference.com) where they ask authors to submit their work as abstract only consisting of limited 1200 words. The abstract should include [Introduction (300 words), Methods (300 words), Results (300 words) and Conclusions with Contributions (300 words)]. At this time, I already have my research work in 8 pages in IEEE format.

The conference is B rank according to ERA2010 requirements. So if I decided to submit my work there and got accepted, will it be less influential than being accepted with IEEE conference that publishes authors work in 8 double column format papers?

Comment: Conferences may ask for abstracts before they are held. I would expect them to request a full paper (and maybe also a copy of the presentation, depending on the conference) for inclusion in the proceedings afterwards. At least it would be weird to have conference proceedings consisting only of abstracts...

Comment: @DetlevCM Proceedings are massively field dependent. In chemistry (for instance), many conferences don't publish proceedings, or publishing a proceedings paper is optional.

Comment: @WanderingChemist: CS/EE is the outlier.

Answer (score 1):

The conference link that you have provided ([here](http://www.ectconference.com/)) is not ranked in recent CORE-2018 database. So, if it is your hard work, you might want to be extra cautious about going ahead with this conference.

Moreover this conference is too generic. I would advise you to go for a specialized conference in your research area. Conferences are not just for publication, they offer way more than just that. You get chance to meet researchers around the globe. If the conference is specialized, then it would be really helpful to get some real feedback and inputs.

Generic conferences do offer some of the benefits, but are not comparable.

Regarding submission to this conference: You could put up your full paper as a preprint in any server and give a link to this shorter version.

Comment: The conference may not be in CORE because it's not a Computer Science conference, but an Engineering conference, focusing on computing methods in Engineering.